# Save data to plist in xcode

Tags: objective-c, plist

I understand that you have to retrieve data from plist first, add data, and rewrite the entire contents to the plist file.

But my code here is NOT appending, but refreshing every time I call this method.

```
- (void) saveDataToPlist {
    // Retrieve path and filename of the plist file
    NSString *myColorsListFile = [self dataFilePath];

    NSMutableArray  *innerArray1;
    NSString *error;

    UserGivenColorHexString = HexTextField.text;
    NSMutableDictionary *rootObj = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:100];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myColorsListFile]) {
        // File exists
        rootObj = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myColorsListFile];


        [innerArray1 addObjectsFromArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:myColorsListFile]];
        [innerArray1 addObject:UserGivenColorName];

    } else {
        // Create file
        rootObj = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        innerArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: UserGivenColorName, nil];
        [rootObj setObject:innerArray1 forKey:@"ColorName"];
    }

    id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:(id)rootObj format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

    [plist writeToFile:myColorsListFile atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a bunch of issues: The key problem is that you are not setting the `innerArray1` variable if the plist was found, so your attempts to add to it will be for naught. After loading `rootObj` with the contents of the plist, you have to obtain a reference to the array located at the key `ColorName`:

```
innerArray1 = [rootObj objectForKey:@"ColorName"];
```

Then the code will work.

Unrelated to this immediate isse, there are a few other minor issues:

- You are reading the dictionary with the `myColorsListFile` plist, but you also try to add the contents of this as an array to `innerArray1`. That latter use of `myColorsListFile` strikes me as an invalid use of this plist. I'd remove that line.
- It appears that you set `UserGivenColorHexString`, but then save `UserGivenColorName` (I might also change this to a local variable to avoid unintended consequences elsewhere). I assume you meant to use the same variable for both of these.
- You're also instantiating mutable dictionary that you're subsequently discarding.
- I might suggest conforming to [Cocoa Naming Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/codingguidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE) (start variables with lowercase letters). I also presumed that `hexTextField` was really a property.
- It might be a little more robust to separate "does the file exist" logic from the "did I find ColorName array" logic.
- Since you're capturing the plist creation failure error, you might as well log it if you encounter it.
- The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nspropertylistserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/dataFromPropertyList%3aformat%3aerrorDescription%3a) tells us that `dataFromPropertyList` is now obsolete:

  > **Special Considerations**
  >
  > This method is obsolete and will be deprecated soon. Use `dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:` instead.

So, you might end up with something like:

```
- (void) saveDataToPlist {
    // Retrieve path and filename of the plist file
    NSString *myColorsListFile = [self dataFilePath];

    NSMutableArray  *innerArray1;
    NSError *error;

    NSString *userGivenColorHexString = HexTextField.text;
    NSMutableDictionary *rootObj;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myColorsListFile]) {
        rootObj = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myColorsListFile];
    } else {
        rootObj = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    innerArray1 = [rootObj objectForKey:@"ColorName"];

    if (innerArray1) {
        [innerArray1 addObject:userGivenColorHexString];
    } else {
        innerArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: userGivenColorHexString, nil];
        [rootObj setObject:innerArray1 forKey:@"ColorName"];
    }

    id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:(id)rootObj format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&error];
    if (!plist) {
        NSLog(@"dataFromPropertyList error: %@", error);
    }

    [plist writeToFile:myColorsListFile atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Rob, I don't have enough reputation to vote your post/solution UP. But if I could I would have done it a 100 times more. Your solution works perfectly, and all your comments are appreciated. Thanks!